# View counter works on local but not server

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to grab some data on what page people are viewing on my website.  I created a php file that makes entries into my database.  The file works on my localhost but when i pushed it up to my server, it worked for every page except my /index.php.  For some reason any time someone went to the home page, it would count them as 3 views, and if someone went to a different page it would count them for that page and the /index.php as well.  I have been poking at this for an hour now, and any ideas would help.  Thank you.

Below is the php document that is included in each page.  It takes the last part of the website and uses it as the page.
  Exp:  www.something.com/customers.php
  in the database should go Table pages rows with name == /customers.php increase counter by one and add the time_stamp.  If it's not there create the row starting at 1 counter.

```
 <?php
 /**
  * Created by PhpStorm.
   * User: Sari
   * Date: 2/13/14
   * Time: 9:53 AM
   */
  $connect = db_connect();
  $qry_insert='';
  $qry_update='';
  $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  $date = date("m/d/y ha", time());
  $qry_string = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE name = '".$page."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$qry_string);
  if($result->num_rows>0){
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
      $counter = $row['counter']+1;
      $time_stamp = $row['time_stamps'].' , '.$date;
      $qry_update= "UPDATE pages SET counter = '".$counter.
                    "' , time_stamps = '".$time_stamp."' WHERE name = '".$page."'";
      mysqli_query($connect,$qry_update);
  }else{
      $qry_insert = "INSERT INTO pages (name , counter , time_stamps) 
                    VALUES ('".$page."' , '1' , '".$date."' )";
      mysqli_query($connect,$qry_insert);
  }
      mysqli_close($connect);
  ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any redirections or rewrite rules on your live server?  Do you have HTML markup with missing `src=` attributes, like `<img src=''> <link href=''>`? Those would cause multiple requests to the same script because of the empty src/href.

Comment: Look in your access log. Do you see three requests to `index.php` for every 1 expected?

Comment: I do not have any redirect nor broken src or href's.  I am not sure how to look at the access logs.  I am using firefox with fire bug.  And i also  have google chrome.

Comment: In Firefox or Chrome, open the Network tab of developer console and watch as the page loads. Do you see multiple requests for index.php?

Comment: No there is only one request for the site.

Comment: I take that back.  It was a missing image.  The img src='' wasn't empty, it was that the file was missing and that's what was causing it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a broken img src=""  Thanks to Michael Berkowski I was able to find it and solve the issue.